# postscript : how to redefine setpagedevice

Tags: postscript

I receive postscript files that include various calls to setpagedevice,
sometimes from within functions and some calls even specify the systemdict version with
systemdict /setpagedevice get exec

However these calls are completely inappropriate for the printer I am using

My idea is:
a) capture the real built in setpagedevice for use in my "custom" version
b) make it so that existing calls to setpagedevice either do nothing or reroute to my custom version

I will then inject my version just after the %%Page lines

So the principle is quite simple but I am completely new to Postscript and the required syntax is not obvious to the newcomer

I could just search and replace existing calls using regex but it seems the postscript language is designed to enable this sort of manipulation of code as data, so it would be nice to know how to do it

Any help appreciated

Update: learning a bit more I have now read that systemdict is read only so the construction systemdict /setpagedevice get exec is pretty much set in stone. It seems like bad style to use this form as it frustrates the manipulation of code as data that I am trying to do, even though the language itself allows it.

Answer (score 0):

If the code says something like this:

```
1 dict begin /PageSize [612 792] currentdict end setpagedevice
```

or this:

```
<< /PageSize [612 792] >> setpagedevice
```

then try this at the beginning of the file or each page if desired:

```
/setpagedevice {pop} def
```

That will just redefine the setpagedevice operator to remove the unwanted new dictionary entry and nothing else.

This would fail when the code fetches the systemdict version of setpagedevice instead of the above version. Maybe a search and replace would work instead:

```
/donotsetpagedevice {pop} def
```

Then search for "setpagedevice" and replace with "donotsetpagedevice" for example.

Or even easier would be to search for "setpagedevice" and replace with "pop".

Comment: Regarding this line of code:
/setpagedevice {pop} def
After that line, how would I then set the page settings how I need them?
I would need first to somehow capture the "native" setpagedevice - perhaps with def and bind?

I have used your final suggestion and replaced occurrences of setpagedevice with pop.
Though with such a flexible layout the regular expressions were tricky
I found it kind of unsatisfactory that I could not achieve my objective using the language itself.

Comment: Do you have your own printer? The setpagedevice is mostly intended to be used with big printers and many users to override the default printer settings. The printer settings can be set at the printer so the individual print jobs don't need to override those defaults. The duplexing can be turned on or off at the printer so the postscript files won't need to use any setpagedevice at all for example. What is your objective actually?

Comment: Here is a postscript program to download and run on your printer to find the current settings: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wplIEiqKkjL965Cj3Ss3_ECT5tVUxhs5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the link but it does not look like any postscript code I have seen? But that is probably just my ignorance.

Comment: This is an automated service which receives thousands of postscript files and with each one an indication of what type of document it is and which one of hundreds of large printers (of various makes)  it is to be sent to. So I need to remove or nullify any device settings contained within the postscript files and replace them with my own (source trays, duplexing, collating, stapling etc) based on what the service has been told about the document type and destination printer

Comment: My first thought was to set the device just before showpage, but I now know that that is too late. The device settings have to be set up before the start of the "build up" of the page. But if I put my device setting just after the %%Page: comments, there is no guarantee that code executed later will not reset the device. There is no marker I know of which says: ok I am going to start the page now, so you better have your device set up.

Comment: The link was for postscript to be sent to a printer and being displayed by Google Artifex Ghostscript not a printer so be sure to download the postscript not the pdf file. That might not be useful for your purposes. I think I am out of my depth with your needs seeing the variety of print jobs and printers you are handing. I wonder if you are reinventing the wheel when there are printer drivers made by Xerox and Lexmark and probably HP that are already made to cope with the demands of your project. The printer drivers use the PPD for each printer and can use the IPP for print job settings.

Comment: I think that printing via a driver would require things that are not supported in a windows service (System.Drawing, System.Printing etc) see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/06/24/printing-from-a-windows-service/ But that article is quite old so perhaps things have improved

Comment: Congratulations on cleaning out the errant settings in your postscript files. To insert your own settings check this link showing these example setpagedevice settings being shown at the very beginning of an example postscript file: http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/docs/P_4110ST/userdocs/any-os/en/PDL_Reference_Guide_Xerox4110_K1.3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the above comments: what I have done is run the files through a series of regular expressions to replace any calls to setpagedevice so that they are effectively noops. Then put my own setpagedevice code just after the %%Page: comment

It is working but of course depends on the postscript files being DSC compliant (or at least having the %%Page comments)

I was disappointed not to be able to detect when the first ink was about to be put on the page and insert my code at that point. I think to do that I would have to write my own postscript interpreter